# Find IDs that have matching rows, using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| entry_id | item_id | stat_id | stat_type | int_value | string_value |
+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|        1 | 4255    |      10 | int       |        54 | NULL         |
|        2 | 4255    |      16 | int       |       443 | NULL         |
|        3 | 4255    |      56 | int       |        13 | NULL         |
|        4 | 6544    |      10 | int       |        54 | NULL         |
|        5 | 6544    |      56 | int       |        13 | NULL         |
|        6 | 6544    |      16 | int       |       443 | NULL         |
|        7 | 8570    |      56 | int       |        13 | NULL         |
|        8 | 8570    |      10 | int       |        76 | NULL         |
|        9 | 8570    |      72 | int       |         1 | NULL         |
+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

The above is an example of a table I have.
The task is to provide the table with a target "item_id" value, getting back an "item_id" that has identical rows to the target.

In the example above, providing the "item_id" of 4255 would return 6544, at those two "item_id" values are both found in three rows, each row otherwise matching one another (with the exception of "entry_id").

In essence, I need to find out if there is another "item_id" in the database, that is in all respects identical to the target. If it has identical rows but is also found in additional rows, it would not be classed as a match.

Is it possible to do this sort of thing as part of an SQL query?
I am currently doing this in a C# code, where I go through every row containing the target "item_id" one by one, looking for matches. This seems very inefficient.

Comment: Not only is this an interesting question, but it is quite well-written for a first question on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have no duplicates (the combination `(item_id, stat_id, stat_type, int_value, string_value)` is unique) and only `string_value` can be NULL, then you can join on exact matches and compare the row count (number of mathces must be equal to the number of rows for both items).

```
select t2.item_id
from t t1
join t t2 using(stat_id, stat_type, int_value)
where t1.item_id = 4255
  and t2.item_id <> t1.item_id
  and t2.string_value <=> t1.string_value
group by t1.item_id, t2.item_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t where t.item_id = 4255)
   and count(*) = (select count(*) from t where t.item_id = t2.item_id)
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/RIU87596

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way in MySQL is to use `group_concat()`.  It is a little bit of a hack, but it should work well -- assuming you can be a little bit flexible with `NULL`:

```
select t.item_id
from (select item_id,
             group_concat(stat_id, '|', stat_type, '|', int_value, '|', coalesce(string_value, '<NULL>' order by stat_id) as fields
      from t
      group by item_id
     ) t join
     (select item_id,
             group_concat(stat_id, '|', stat_type, '|', int_value, '|', coalesce(string_value, '<NULL>' order by stat_id) as fields
      from t
      where item_id = 4255
     ) tspecial
     on tspecial.fields = t.fields;
```

Caveats:

- This requires some special-purpose processing of `NULL`.
- By default, the length of the internal string used for `group_concat()` is 1,024 characters.  This can be overridden, if needed.
- This assumes that the fields don't have the separation character (`'|'`).

A relational solution is a bit more complicated.

```
select i.item_id
from (select distinct item_id from t) i cross join
     (select stat_id, stat_type, int_value, string_value
      from t where item_id = 4255
     ) s left join
     t
     on t.stat_id = s.stat_id and
        t.stat_type = s.stat_type and
        t.int_value is not distinct from s.int_value and
        t.string_value is not distinct from s.string_value
group by i.item_id
having count(*) = count(t.stat_id);
```

How does this work?  It generates all the stats for the field you want with all the items.  Then it does a `left join` to match the values in the other fields.  The aggregation then checks that the number of matching stats matches the number expected.

One advantage is that this version doesn't have the weird limitations on `NULL` values or separator characters.